# No module named 'manage_db.tools'; 'manage_db' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

**I have a Package that works with the Django Framework.
I'm trying to import two packages that are outside the Django package, so that I can work with their Python files.**

**In order for Django to recognize the packages, I added the following lines to the Django settings file:**

```
manage_db = os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent.parent, "manage_db")
g = os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent.parent, "g")
sys.path.append(manage_db)
sys.path.append(g)
```

**And in the views.py file I wrote:**

```
from g.globals import Globals
from manage_db.execute_get_symbols import get_symbols
```

**The error I got is:**

- No module named 'manage_db.execute_get_symbols'; 'manage_db' is not a package
- For the second package - No module named 'g'

.

- I read from people who had similar problems that they changed the names of the directories, and it worked for them,
  I tried, and I change the name to "g", but it didn't work.

**Note:** I created the packages, they are not packs that require pip install

**Thanks in advance to all the helpers.**

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path had to be added in the settings file so that all packages would be recognized at runtime.

I added the code in the setting file, the code is:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent.parent, ""))  # To get the path from root until current directory
```